# FilePicker widget does not respond on release mod

Tags: flutter, dart, file, filepicker

I am using [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) dependency on my project. I have simple icon button and it opens default file picker as it should be on debug mod.(Both android and web-chrome debug.)

```
 IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        FilePickerResult? result =
                            await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

                        if (result != null) {
                          File file = File(result.files.single.path!);
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                              .showSnackBar(fileSending);
                          MessageViewModel()
                              .sendMedia(file: file, chatID: args.chatID!);
                        } else {
                          // User canceled the picker
                        }
                      },
```

However, there is no respond on release mod. (flutter build web, firebase hosting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.
Just flutter clean and rebuild it...